# using mysql query for fetch the data from database in php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

using query more than 4 query for fetch the data base the four query are run properly but i use one more query for fetch the hotel_id and this hotel_id use in different query but when i run the query, the query run properly but didn't get output in while loop and what is my mistake in the code..... this query working properly but $query1 = "select hotel_id from menu_master where menu_id=".$id; but in $hid = $row['hotel_id']; can't store any value in $hid..

```
$query1 = "select hotel_id from menu_master where menu_id=".$id;
                    $res = mysql_query( $query1);
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
                    {
                        $hid = $row['hotel_id'];
                    }

                    $query = "select set_rank from menu_master where menu_id = $row_id and hotel_id='".$_REQUEST['hotel_id']."'";
                    //echo $query."<br/>";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);

                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $current_rank = $row['set_rank'];
                    }

                    $current_id = $row_id;
                    $new_rank =$_REQUEST['set_rank'];

                     $sql = "select * from menu_master where set_rank = '$new_rank ' and hotel_id='".$_REQUEST['hotel_id']."'" ;    
                     $rs = mysql_query($sql);

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
                         {  
                                $menu_id = $row['menu_id'];
                                $sql="update menu_master 
                                set set_rank=$current_rank where menu_id= $menu_id and hotel_id='".$_REQUEST['hotel_id']."'";

                                mysql_query($sql);

                         }

                                    $sql="update menu_master set 
                                    hotel_id           = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['hotel_id'])."',
                                    menu_name          = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['menu_name'])."',
                                    menu_name_ar       = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['menu_name_ar'])."',
                                    is_active          = '".$is_active."',
                                    set_rank=$new_rank where menu_id= '$current_id' and hotel_id='".$_REQUEST['hotel_id']."'";
                                    mysql_query($sql);
                }
```

Comment: [Don't use mysql_* extension](http://www.php.net/en/mysql_query) as they’re deprecated. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MSQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: How do you the query is working properly? Have you tested it in SQL? Does it retrieve the result there, but not in the code?

Comment: Ivo Pereira 
select hotel_id from menu_master where menu_id=".$id; in this query fetch the hotel_id but i use the while loop didn't get output from table

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$query1 = "select hotel_id from menu_master where menu_id=".$id;
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query1));
$hid = $row['hotel_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

$query1 = "select hotel_id from menu_master where menu_id=".$id;

```
                $res = mysql_query( $query1);

                while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($res))
                {


                    $hid = $row1['hotel_id'];

                $query = "select set_rank from menu_master where menu_id = $row_id and hotel_id='".$hid."'";
                //echo $query."<br/>";
                $result = mysql_query($query);

                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $current_rank = $row['set_rank'];
                }

                $current_id = $row_id;
                $new_rank =$_REQUEST['set_rank'];

                 $sql = "select * from menu_master where set_rank = '$new_rank ' and hotel_id='".$hid."'" ;    
                 $rs = mysql_query($sql);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
                     {  
                            $menu_id = $row['menu_id'];
                            $sql="update menu_master 
                            set set_rank=$current_rank where menu_id= $menu_id and hotel_id='".$hid."'";

                            mysql_query($sql);

                     }

                                $sql="update menu_master set 
                                hotel_id           = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['hotel_id'])."',
                                menu_name          = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['menu_name'])."',
                                menu_name_ar       = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['menu_name_ar'])."',
                                is_active          = '".$is_active."',
                                set_rank=$new_rank where menu_id= '$current_id' and hotel_id='".$hid."'";
                                mysql_query($sql);
            }
```